# Titanium: How to use Google Maps on iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, android-mapview, titanium-mobile

I'm working on a app with a Titanium map module. Building this app for Android and iOS. Currently, on Android devices map module uses Google Maps, on iOS devices (iphone,ipad..etc) map module uses iMaps. Is there a way that I can use Google maps in the iOS devices as well (instead of using iMaps) ?

I'm using standard titanium map view.

```
var mapview = Titanium.Map.createView({
   mapType: Titanium.Map.STANDARD_TYPE,
   region: MyRegion,
   regionFit:true,
   userLocation:true,
   annotations:[annotation]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

see the following official URL:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/intro?hl=es

Comment: I checked the link above, Will this work with titanium studio?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I bet that if, as titanium is a fork of eclipse.